# Why does the suffix -ful sometimes mean "evoking," and is there a pattern among the words for which this is true?

Tags: suffixes

The suffix *-ful* usually means *characterized by* or *in full measure* as in *hateful* and *spoonful*. But an animal's *pitiful cry* is not full of, or characterized by, pity, and the *fearful symmetry*  of Blake's tyger is not full of fear. These meanings run counter to what one might naively think. How did this come about? I understand that the suffixes -ful and -ous are part of the battle between words that come through French and those that don't. Sometimes the meanings of prefixes and suffixes change dramatically at the hands of the French.  *Para-* usually means *beside*, but in words through the French, like *parachute, paraph* and *parasol*, it means *against.* Does this have any bearing on my question? I see the meanings of *piteous* and *pitiful* are frightfully close.

Comment: Interestingly, "hateful" can also mean "evoking hatred" rather than "possessing hatred."

Comment: The two different senses of _para-_ are etymologically distinct: the ‘beside’ one is from the Greek preposition _παρά_ ‘along, beside, etc.’; the ‘against’ is from Romance languages and is verbal in origin, from _parar(e)_ ‘stop, block’. Romance languages often employ verb-object compounds (which are extremely rare in native words in Germanic languages), and _parachute_ is literally a ‘stop-fall’, _parasol_ a ‘stop-sun’. Other examples of this are Fr. _porte-monnaie_ ‘carry-money (= wallet)’ or Sp. _chupa-cabra_ ‘suck-goat (= chupacabra)’.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet Your observation about the origins of verb-object compounds is insightful. I suppose "portmanteau" is another example, which I would have pinned on the French.

Comment: @Airymouse Yup, that’s another one. When creating nominal compounds from verbal phrases, Germanic languages tend to have the object preceding the verb and sticking with agent nouns (_truck-driver_) or participles (_happy-looking_, _shit-faced_). This type of compounding is virtually unknown in the Romance languages, where instead the [terpsimbrotos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terpsimbrotos) type is used: the verb comes first (usually just the inflectional stem is used), followed by the object. There’s no morphological marker to show agent nouns, but the meaning is still agentive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Online Etymology Dictionary [notes](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ful)

> Most English *-ful* adjectives at one time or another had both passive ("full of x") and active ("causing x; full of occasion for x") senses.

Consider the following: an act of gang violence can be *disgraceful* (effecting disgrace) or a gang can be *disgraceful* (marked by disgrace); a *joyful* person feels joy, while a *joyful* occasion brings joy; a *regretful* decision may be one that causes regret but a *regretful* person demonstrates regret.

But in other cases, one or the other meaning never developed, or has died out. For example, the oldest meaning of *pitiful* in the OED is

> (from ca. 1350) 1. Full of or characterized by pity; compassionate, merciful, tender. Cf. *pitiable adj. 1.*

But it is *Now rare.*, and later senses of *pitiful* as *something deserving of pity* and thence *contemptible* have become the dominant meanings.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be from the original Old English meaning of "ful": characterized by:

***[-ful](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=-ful):***

> - ***word-forming element attached to nouns*** (and in modern English to verb stems) ***and meaning "full of, having, characterized by,"*** also "amount or volume contained" (handful, bellyful); ***from Old English -full, -ful, which is full (adj.) become a suffix by being coalesced with a preceding noun, but originally a separate word.*** Cognate with German -voll, Old Norse -fullr, Danish -fuld. Most English -ful adjectives at one time or another had both passive ("full of x") and active ("causing x; full of occasion for x") senses.

(Etymonline)